# Как сделать, чтобы при клике на заголовок меню развернулось/свернулось подменю?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Как сделать, чтобы при клике на заголовок меню развернулось подменю, и так же закрывалось при клике?

Comment: что Вы пробовали сделать и что у Вас не получилось?

Comment: если Вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста отметьте подходящий ответ как [решение Вашего вопроса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)(зеленая галка под цифрой слева от текста ответа).

Answer (score 5):

Вариант с добавлением класса

```js
$(function() {
  $('.menu').click(function() {
    if($('.submenu').hasClass('a')){
      $('.submenu').removeClass('a');
    }else{
      $('.submenu').addClass('a');
    };
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.submenu {display:none;}
.submenu.a {display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="" class="menu">Я пункт меню :)</a>
<ul class="submenu">
  <li>Пункт 1</li>
  <li>Пункт 2</li>
  <li>Пункт 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Так проще `toggleClass`. А в jQuery UI есть даже версия метода `toggleClass` с различными анимациями.

Answer (score 4):

Вариант с [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

> Переключает режим отображения каждого из элементов набора. Если
>   элемент скрыт, то данная функция отображает его (используя метод
>   *show*); если элемент видимый -- скрывает его (используя метод *hide*).

```js
$(function() {
  $('.menu').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.submenu').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.submenu{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" title="" class="menu">Я еще один пункт меню</a>
<ul class="submenu">
  <li>Пункт 1</li>
  <li>Пункт 2</li>
  <li>Пункт 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Блин, забыл про эту функцию )

Comment: @Yuri ничего страшного, бывает ) я просто не хотел писать, т.к. вопрос достаточно простой, дубликаты бы поискать...

Comment: **This method signature was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9** — надо знать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский почитал про *deprecated toggle*, выяснилось, что [toggle работает до сих пор (в т.ч. в последних версиях jquery)](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/). Изменилось количество обработчиков до 2-х, [был убран обработчик "*дополнительные обработчики для циклического переключения после клика*"](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/).

Comment: Ну если так, то хорошо

Answer (score 4):

**Например [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/):**

```js
$('.trigger').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $('#js-menu').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
#js-menu {
  display: none;
}

#js-menu.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>

  <button class="trigger"> &#926;</button>
  
  <ul id="js-menu">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
  </ul>
```

**Или [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/):**

```js
$('.trigger').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $('#js-menu').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
#js-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>

  <button class="trigger"> &#926;</button>
  
  <ul id="js-menu">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Главное потом не забыть, что сигнатура `.toggleClass( [state ] )` — **is deprecated as of jQuery 3.0.**

Answer (score 3):

Вариант без использования классов, без дополнительной разметки, без CSS, без jQuery — чистый JS.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button')
const ul = document.querySelector('ul')

ul.setAttribute('hidden', true)

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  ul.toggleAttribute('hidden')
})
```

```html
<button>click me</button>
<ul>
  <li>ololo 1
    <li>ololo 2
      <li>ololo 3
</ul>
```

Comment: Моэно использовать toggleAttribute в таком случае - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/toggleAttribute

Comment: @AlexandrVyshnyvetskyi обновил код, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

На чистом `js` -

```js
let nav = document.body.querySelector('.nav');

nav.addEventListener('click', nav_clickHandler);

function nav_clickHandler( {target} ){
  if( target.classList.contains('dropdown') ){
    let item = target.parentNode.querySelector(`[data-target="${target.dataset.toogle}"]`);
    let state = item.dataset.active;
    
    item.dataset.active = state === "true" ? false : true;
  }
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  
  padding: 0;
}

[data-active="false"] {
  height: 0;
  
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
    <span class="dropdown" data-toogle="first">first</span>
    <ul data-target="first" data-active="false">
      <li><span>first 1</span></li>
      <li><span>first 1</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="dropdown" data-toogle="second">second</span>
    <ul data-target="second" data-active="false">
      <li><span>second 1</span></li>
      <li><span>second 1</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

На чистом `css` (его не советуют в коментах и я с этим согласен, но все же оставлю его) -

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  
  padding: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + ul {
  height: 0;
  
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <label for="first-section">first</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="first-section" hidden>
    <ul class="slider">
      <li><span>first 1</span></li>
      <li><span>first 2</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="second-section">second</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="second-section" hidden>
    <ul class="slider">
      <li><span>second 1</span></li>
      <li><span>second 2</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: жуткий способ для меню\навигации )

Comment: @Alex а я просто этого не знаю, я как вариант показал.

Comment: @Elena для меня не менее жутко использовать jq в 2017 году :)

Comment: @OlmerDale вы из будущего?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский если Вы не о погрешности в несколько дней, то я реально считаю что использование jq это несколько шагов назад. Уже несколько лет как полностью решена проблема с поддержкой браузерами и сам js стал лучше чем jq. Использовать её сегодня означает вычеркнуть пункт о саморазвитии на будущие.

Comment: @OlmerDale вы еще в ноябре писали про 2017 и ее раньше где-то... Это нельзя назвать погрешностью в несколько дней)) js стал лучше, но тем не менее и jquery не тормоз и добавляет много фичей. а в js хоть и появляется что-то удобное, все равно приходится велосипедить чтоб сделать некий начальный файл с частыми используемыми функциями. что, по-сути, превращает это велосипедостроение в написание файла, наподобие jquery, только меньше по размерам))

Comment: @OlmerDale, т.е. jq прошлое, а использовать чекбоксы для пунктов меню это будещее?! Ваш способ только в кунсткамеру!

Comment: @Elena я когда узнал что так можно, для меня это было открытием. И этот пример я сделал только ради того, чтобы показать автору что можно и так. Только я не додумался об этом сказать. Я вообще часто отвечаю по css только потому, что мне интересно сделать задачу нестандартным способом. По сути я просто тренируюсь. А в кунскамеры... Там все уже давно jq забито!